# X Forwarded For Showing Origin IP

Tags: nginx, proxy, http-headers, proxypass

My X-Forwarded-For header is showing my origin IP. I am routing traffic via Cloudflare and I know it's touchy with that header. I changed it to MYNAME-Forwarded-For just to check and it still shows the origin. Does anyone have any experience seeing the origin IP in a proxy chain? I don't want the origin exposed! Thanks. Nginx with Ubuntu btw. I have an Ngninx 'load balancer' sitting in front of my server.

Comment: You don't want the "origin" exposed to whom? There are very important bits left out of this question. Such as: A description of your stack. What you mean by "origin". Why you aren't using CF-Connecting-IP.

Comment: You're right. I have an NGINX 'load balancer' sitting in front of my back end server. I am hoping to add the connecting client ip to the response from my server. Is this doable? I'd likely add it to the headers when the request hits the load balancer no? It's a simple wordpress site on the back end, I'm just trying to teach myself about load balancers/headers/etc. Can I add the client IP to the response header? As of now my  $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for; is showing both the client connecting IP and the IP of my origin server behind the load balancer. I don't want that. @MichaelHampton. Thanks.

Comment: Well, that's what it is _supposed_ to be doing. Again, why aren't you using CF-Connecting-IP?